# How can I find the password to www-data group to so I can change directory access rights?

Tags: virtualbox, passwd

I am running Ubuntu on a Oracle Vbox in Windows 7 to develop a website.  I have a set of directories that have owner read/write permissions but the group www-data does not have rights on the directories.

I tried the command  `sudo chmod 640 /path-to-directory` to change the status, but receive a message requesting my www-data password.  My owner level password does not work and I do not know what this password might be.

I tried `passwd` and receive the message 'changing the password for www-data and a prompt for my current password.  When I enter it, I get this error message:

> passwd: Authentication token manipulation error 
>   passwd: password unchanged

This error message looks more like some sort of problem on my system, but everything else works fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're doing it wrong (tm) :)

In your terminal window, look at the "command prompt":

```
username@hostname:~$
```

What is `username` there? You can also try entering `whoami`[Enter] to see your current username.

From you description it looks like you entered something like

```
sudo su www-data
```

or somehow else opened a console session as www-data user. This user has no rights to use `sudo` command, so your attempts at using `sudo` fail.

`www-data` user also has no password set by default, so it is impossible to log in directly as this user. Which is good. You do not want to give it a password.

You need to open another session as your user (or exit your current `www-data` session) and type the commands there:

```
sudo chown yourusername:www-data /path/to/directory
```

which will ask you for your login password.

(or, maybe, just move your stuff to `/var/www` which already has correct permissions. Then you can add your user to www-data group to get read-write privileges to that directory)

Comment: Thanks, but I am a bit confused.  "whoamI" tells me I am www-data, even in the system directories.  So I attempted to switch users and the only name listed is my unix (owner) name, but that is linked to this www-data session.  This setup was generated automatically to run a Drupal website and I do not understand the subtleties of Ubuntu.  How do I go about logging in with my owner identity?   BTW I tried moving the directories to /var/www, but I do not have the authority to do so as www-data.

Comment: Open another terminal window. Type `whoami` there. Are you still www-data there? I'm not sure what you mean by "unix (owner) name" - what username do you enter when logging in? Is something like "ashlar" or "admin" or is it "www-data"?

Comment: I opened a separate question on this here http://askubuntu.com/questions/124073 and will add responses there.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood your instructions. I was able to start another terminal session as the owner and make the changes!

Comment: why is it good that you cannot use the www-data user??

Comment: I did not say you can't use, I said you can't log in as that user directly. Which is good from the security point of view

Comment: I have a situation: my local computer is a temporary server, to which my co-worker connects and sends some data via ssh, creating directories and files in my local web-project, that is running on nginx. I don't see another way here but to give `www-data` a password to be able to connect as that `www-data`.

Comment: @Boolean_Type: There's always a way :) One option: create a group called "my-local-web-project", add "boolean-type", "coworker" and "www-data" users to that group, make sure the files have read/write permissions for the group.

Comment: @Sergey Yeah, that's a way, unless files should have "644" permissions.

Answer (score 2):

To allow user www-data to login with WinSCP in a local vmware running ubuntu follow these steps:

1. Edit the password file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/passwd
   ```
2. Alter

   ```
   www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
   ```
3. to

   ```
   www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash
   ```
4. Save.
5. Set the password for www-data

   ```
   sudo passwd www-data
   ```
6. You can now login using www-data user.

Answer (score -1):

To change password use this command **sudo passwd username** ,change username with user you want to set new password,but also you should check ownership and group of particular directory.
Use this command
**ls -l /path/to/file**  #the third field in the ls -l output is the user and the fourth is the group

You can change group and ownership with **chown**